# log4net log file is not created using log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am new to Log4Net. I am trying to use this logger for logging my MVC application

I am having trouble using this, as the log file is not getting created.

It is building successfully, no error is thrown.

```
<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="UserLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

      <!--<file value="C:\\Users\madhu.GIHOS\New folder.log" />-->
      <file value="filepath.log" />
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
      <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyyy" />
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline Date Stamp: %date{dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss,fff}. %5rms %newline%logger                         %newline&gt;&gt; %message%newline %newline%-------------------------------------------------------------------------" />
        <!--<conversionPattern value="%d - %m%n"/>-->
      </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: how do you use it in your program?

Comment: Does the web site's service account have permission to write to your target location? Use Process Monitor to determine if an attempt to write the file is being made. You will need to add relevant filters to trim down the number of events it captures: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you actually defining which appender to use in your config file?

```
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="UserLog" />
  </root>
```